# difference between =v1 and (v1)?

Tags: c++, vector

What the difference between:

```
vector<int> v4=v1;
```

and:

```
vector<int> v4(v1);
```

Aren't both the same thing and call copy c'tor?

Note: v1 and v4 are vectors of int

Comment: And what is v1?

Comment: q.v. Nicolai Josuttis "The Nightmare of Initialization in C++" presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: both are vectors